# EBS 12.2 form personalisation , Supervisior field is mandatory but still am able to save the records

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oracle-ebs

I made the supervisor field in Assignment screen mandatory by form personalisation but when i save the records without entering data in Supervisor field it allows me to save the record.

```
FORM PERSONALISATION parameters
Trigger Event :- WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE
Processing Mode :- NOT-IN-ENTER-QUERY-MODE
ACTION
SEQ :- 10
TYPE :- PROPERTY
LANGUAGE :- ALL
OBJECT TYPE :- ITEM
TARGET OBJECT :- ASSGT.SUPERVISOR_NAME
PROPERTY NAME :- REQUIRED
VALUE :- TRUE
```

Comment: It is set when you run the form, but not in enter query mode. So - do you do that? If it is in query mode, that item won't be set as *required*.

Comment: Yes, it's set as required and also the field is highlighted by yellow color in the form